# How to delete files coresponding to TreeView checked nodes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, treeview

I want to delete treenodes from the treeview,but also from the specified folder.
This is what I try to do,but seems like something is wrong...
    I searched the web a lot and everywhere is about deleting everything from a specified path(clear).
Thanks a lot !

```
void RemoveCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        string currentLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Notes";
        List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Checked)
            {
                checkedNodes.Add(node);
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveCheckedNodes(node.Nodes);
            }
        }

        foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
        {
            nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
            string[] path = new string[checkedNodes.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                path[i]=(currentLocation + "\\" + nodes + ".txt");
                File.Delete(path[i]);
            }                    

        } 
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: After I select some nodes from Treeview,it deletes from the treeview,but doesnt delete from computer memory.

Comment: Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms question, because WPF doesn't have a TreeNodeCollection class?

Comment: It doesnt throw any exception,just doesnt delete the selected files from the  specified path.I removed WPF tag :D is a WinFormApp,sorry for that.

Comment: The path does not look right. Putting "nodes" in there will probably result in System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection. Try adding a breakpoint and see what the path is that it is trying to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for my delay,but I didnt had access to internet until now...
I found the solution for my problem:

```
 private string currentLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\notes";//curent location of the files
 public void RemoveSelectedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)// delete selected nodes from memory
    {
        List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Checked)
            {
                checkedNodes.Add(node);
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveSelectedNodes(node.Nodes);
            }
        }

        foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
            {
            nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
            string[] path = new string[checkedNodes.Count];
            for (int i=0; i < checkedNodes.Count;i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    path[i] = (currentLocation+ "\\" + checkedNode.Text);
                    File.Delete(path[i]);
                    i++;

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You must select minimum 1 element !");
                }

            } 
       }
```

The code means a treeview populated with .rtf files that can be deleted by selecting from the treeview.

Comment: Why would you create the `path[]` array? Also catching like any `Exception` is not a good idea. Consider catching `IOException` and `UnauthorizedAccessException` if you want to check, whether it is possible to delete the file. Although judging by the message in the messagebox I think you actually meant a `checkedNodes.Count > 0` check before the loop instead of `try catch` block.